# In App Purchase returning invalid products but all code seems correct

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have gone through many posts regarding this issue that seems helpful. The code I am using is the same as others  used  for getting the product information. The only difference I can see is that people are saying their products are "Pending Developer Approval" were as mine are "Waiting For Review".

I submitted my app and then rejected the binary which seems in line with this guide:

[In App Purchases: A Full Walkthrough](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

My question is: do I have to wait for Apple to review my in app purchase before I can start testing with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, as soon as you have submitted the in app purchase for review you might not be able to test them (while in review). Before asking apple to review it, the testing should have been done already. You could add another In App Purchase and test it before submitting it for review and delete your old In App Purchase entry.

In my experience, as soon as you have created an In App Purchase item, it is immediately available for testing with your testaccount.

Comment: I just realized that I had hit submit prematurely. I removed the IAP and now created a new one. It still says "Waiting For Screenshot" while this status is not listed in iTunes Connect FAQ here: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/90.0.0.9.1.7.1.3.3.1

Did yours every say waiting for screenshot when you first created it for testing?

Comment: The docs are not up to date. Apple recently changed the behaviour/status-codes and has not yet updated the faq. You can test the In App Purchase while in _Waiting for screenshot_ status. Just check, that _Cleared for sale_ is set to *YES* (Which is the default). Your `SKProductsRequest` should already work and deliver the new IAP

Comment: Cleared for sale is set to YES but the SKProductsRequest only brings back invalid product ID. :(...Good to know Apple docs aren't up to date though.


GOT IT!  Turns out it accepts "productID" instead of "com.MyDomain.MyAppID.productID"...I always read it was supposed to take the full path, any thoughts or suggestions? Is that wrong?

Comment: The productID in the SKProductsRequest should be exactly as you entered it in the IAP creation within the Product ID field in iTunes Connect. The recommendation is to use reverse domain name, but if you just named it "abcd" there, only "abcd" needs to be sent in the request. It is up to you to specify "com.mydomain.myappid.abcd" within iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

It might be very late, but for anyone else struggling with the same problem:

Make sure you are running it on a device where the user is signed into the app store. I was also facing the same problem while running it on the simulator, my IAP was also on the- waiting for screenshot stage.